# Issue with if statement in PHP code

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, hyperlink

I first had this code:

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    if ($row['class'] <>$class) {
        echo "<tr><td><p class=\"boldtitle\">".$row['class']."</p></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td><a href=\"".$row['hyperlink']."\">".$row['title']."</a></td>
    </tr>
    ";
    $class = $row['class'];
}
}
```

That was working fine, but I want that the HTML hyperlink tag disappears when `".$row['hyperlink']."` is equal to `"NULL"`.

For this, I wrote the code like this:

```
$class = $row['class'];
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    if ($row['class'] <>$class) {
        echo "<tr><td><p class=\"boldtitle\">".$row['class']."</p></td></tr>";
    }
    if ($row['hyperlink'] != "NULL")    {
        echo "<tr><td><a href=\"".$row['hyperlink']."\">".$row['title']."</a></td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td></tr>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Hyperlinks are set or removed as I want, but the grouping function got lost, too.

Instead of:

```
**Cleaner**
David
Phil
Gustav
**Farmer**
Lynn
Peter
**Mason**
Brion
Alf
```

I get:

```
**Cleaner**
David
**Cleaner**
Phil
**Cleaner**
Gustav
**Farmer**
Lynn
**Farmer**
Peter
**Mason**
Brion
**Mason**
Alf
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong? Where's my fault?

Comment: I'm guessing instead of `$row['hyperlink'] != "NULL"` you want `$row['hyperlink'] != null` (no quotes)

Comment: @jszobody perhaps. The question is very vague. We need to know how the data is constructed.

Comment: You have 4 { and 5 }  in your foreach ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second bit of code, you moved the `$class = $row['class'];` outside the foreach loop. That means it will initially be set to null (because `$row['class']` is undefined before the loop), so `$row['class'] <>$class` will always be true. Move it back inside the loop and it should work as before.

```
$class = null; // initialize $class to null
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    if ($row['class'] <>$class) {
        echo "<tr><td><p class=\"boldtitle\">".$row['class']."</p></td></tr>";
    }
    if ($row['hyperlink'] != "NULL") {
        echo "<tr><td><a href=\"".$row['hyperlink']."\">".$row['title']."</a></td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $class = $row['class']; // reset $class to the current value here
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.